# IDEA Ruby plugin code inspection cannot see gem

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, rubygems

Code inspection in the IntelliJ IDEA editor reports a LoadError "no such file to load" on the code

```
require 'state_machine'
```

The gem is installed locally. From the command line:

```
~$ echo $RUBYOPT 
rubygems
~$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'state_machine'
=> true
```

So Ruby and Rubygems are playing nicely together. The IDEA Ruby plugin's project settings even lists the gem, so why can't the editor see it?

Ruby version 1.8.7, IntelliJ IDEA 10.5.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gem must be specified in the `Gemfile`, [refer to help](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/ruby-gems-support.html).

Comment: It's pretty much my first ruby app, I was working without Bundler until now. Thanks